# Reconstructing an optimal Simplex tableau from an optimal solution

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming, operations-research

I have here a bounded LP with infinite optimal solutions:

```
max    60 x1 + 100 x2 +  80 x3
s.t.  144 x1 + 192 x2 + 240 x3 <= 120,000
      100 x1 + 150 x2 + 120 x3 <= 60,000
          x1 +     x2 +     x3 <= 500
                 x >= 0
```

My Operations Research teacher has hinted that you can reconstruct an entire optimal tableau from the optimal solution and the initial LP.  I can easily find the basis and reconstruct the entirety of the tableau, except for the objective row.  What I've done now was a really roundabout way of using MATLAB to find an optimal solution (doing this LP by hand is messy, and we've already had plenty of simplex method homework), finding $B^{-1}$ and multiplying through the tableau, which revealed a simpler optimal solution, and then running the simplex method again by hand, but rigging my choices of entering and leaving variables to get the basis I want.

There's a simpler way, yes?

Answer (score 1):

### Assumptions

- $A \in M_{m\times n}(\Bbb R)$ ($m\le n$) has rank $n$ and basis matrix $B$.
- $x_B$ denotes the basic solution.
- $c_B$ denotes the reduced objective function so that $c^T x=c_B^T x_B$.  (So the *order/arrangement* of basic variables is very important.)

The initial simplex tableau for your problem(, which is already in canoncial form,) will be

\begin{array}{cc|c}
A & I & b \\ \hline
-c^T & 0 & 0
\end{array}

We multiply the $m$ constraints by $B^{-1}$.  Note that $\mathbf{e}_1,\dots,\mathbf{e}_n$ can be found in $[B^{-1}A\;B^{-1}]$ since $B$ is chosen from columns of $[A\;I]$.  We add a linear combination of the first $m$ row to the last row.

\begin{array}{cc|c}
B^{-1}A & B^{-1} & B^{-1}b \\ \hline
c_B^T B^{-1}A-c^T & c_B^T B^{-1} & c_B^T B^{-1}b \tag{*} \label{t1}
\end{array}

Why is $c_B^T$ chosen?  We write $x_B$ as $(x_{B_1},\dots,x_{B_n})^T$.  Choose an index $i$ in $\{1,\dots,n\}$, and suppose that $x_j = x_{B_i}$

Case 1: $1\le j \le n$. In the $j$-th column of the last row,

$$(c_B^T B^{-1}A-c^T)_j = c_B^T B^{-1} \mathbf{a}_j -c_j = c_B^T \mathbf{e}_i - c_j = c_{B_i} - c_j = 0.$$

Case 2: $n+1 \le j \le m+n$.  Note that $c_{B_i}= 0$.  In the $j$-th column of the last row,

$$(c_B^T B^{-1})_{j - n} = c_B^T \mathbf{e}_i = c_{B_i} = 0.$$

Therefore, the entries corresponding to the basic variables in the last row in tableau $\eqref{t1}$ will be zero.  Then, $\eqref{t1}$ is a simplex tableau that you can compute from the given optimal solution.

### Computational results for your example

Here's the GNU Octave code for finding the optimal tableau.  The syntax should be the *same* in MATLAB except for the solver `glpk`.  You may test the code at [Octave Online](http://octave-online.net/).

```
c=[60 100 80]'; A=[144 192 240; 100 150 120; 1 1 1];
b=[120000 60000 500]';
[x_max,z_max]=glpk(c,A,b,[0 0 0]',[],"UUU","CCC",-1)
x=[x_max; b-A*x_max] % Include slack variables
A1=[A eye(3)]; % Part of initial tableau
c1=[c' zeros(1,3)]';
B=A1(:,find(x > 0)')
c_B=c1(find(x > 0));
disp('Initial tableau');
[A1 b; -c1' 0]
disp('Final tableau');
[B^-1*A B^-1 B^-1*b; c_B'*B^-1*A-c' c_B'*B^-1 c_B'*B^-1*b]
```

The computer output

```
x_max =

     0.00000
   400.00000
     0.00000

z_max =    4.0000e+04
x =

   0.0000e+00
   4.0000e+02
   0.0000e+00
   4.3200e+04
  -7.2760e-12
   1.0000e+02

B =

   192     1     0
   150     0     0
     1     0     1

Initial tableau
ans =

      144      192      240        1        0        0   120000
      100      150      120        0        1        0    60000
        1        1        1        0        0        1      500
      -60     -100      -80       -0       -0       -0        0

Final tableau
ans =

 Columns 1 through 6:

   6.6667e-01   1.0000e+00   8.0000e-01   0.0000e+00   6.6667e-03  -0.0000e+00
   1.6000e+01   0.0000e+00   8.6400e+01   1.0000e+00  -1.2800e+00   0.0000e+00
   3.3333e-01   1.1102e-16   2.0000e-01   0.0000e+00  -6.6667e-03   1.0000e+00
   6.6667e+00   0.0000e+00   0.0000e+00   0.0000e+00   6.6667e-01   0.0000e+00

 Column 7:

   4.0000e+02
   4.3200e+04
   1.0000e+02
   4.0000e+04
```

The optimal tableau:

\begin{equation*}
  \begin{array}{ccccccc|l}
        &          x_1 & x_2 &           x_3 & s_1 &            s_2 & s_3 &       \\ \hline
    x_2 &      \frac23 &   1 &       \frac45 &   0 &  \frac{1}{150} &   0 &   400 \\
    s_1 &           16 &   0 & \frac{432}{5} &   1 & -\frac{32}{25} &   0 & 43200 \\
    s_3 &      \frac13 &   0 &       \frac15 &   0 & -\frac{1}{150} &   1 &   100 \\ \hline
        & \frac{20}{3} &   0 &             0 &   0 &        \frac23 &   0 & 40000 \\
  \end{array}
\end{equation*}