# Simplex method - identity matrix

Tags: discrete-mathematics, optimization, linear-programming, simplex

I want to solve the following linear programming problem:

$$\min (5y_1-10y_2+7y_3-3y_4) \\ y_1+y_2+7y_3+2y_4=3 \\ -2y_1-y_2+3y_3+3y_4=2 \\ 2y_1+2y_2+8y_3+y_4=4 \\ y_i \geq 0, i \in \{ 1, \dots, 4 \}$$

$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 7 & 2 & | & 3\\ 
-2 & -1 & 3 & 3 & | & 2\\ 
2 & 2 & 8 & 1 & | & 4
\end{bmatrix} \to \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 7 & 2 & | & 3\\ 
0 & 1 & 17 & 7 & | & 8\\ 
0 & 0 & 6 & 3 & | & 2
\end{bmatrix}$

So the problem is written equivalently as follows:

$$-\max (-5y_1+10y_2-7y_3+3y_4) \\ y_1+y_2+7y_3+2y_4=3 \\ y_2+17y_3+7y_4=8 \\ 6y_3+3y_4=2 \\ y_i \geq 0, i \in \{ 1, \dots, 4 \}$$

But we want the $3 \times 3$ identity matrix to appear at the matrix that represents the linear programming problem, right?

So we solve the following problem, right?

$$-\max (-5y_1+10y_2-7y_3+3y_4) \\ y_1+y_2+7y_3+2y_4=3 \\ y_2+17y_3+7y_4+y_5=8 \\ 6y_3+3y_4+y_6=2 \\ y_i \geq 0, i \in \{ 1, \dots,6 \}$$

Then:

$\begin{matrix}
B & c_B & b & P_1 & P_2 & P_3 & P_4 & P_5 & P_5 & \theta & \\ 
P_1 & -5 & 3 & 1 & 1 & 7 & 2 & 0 & 0 & \frac{3}{7} &L_1 \\ 
P_5 & 0 & 8 & 0 & 1 & 17 & 7 & 1 & 0 & \frac{8}{17} & L_2\\ 
P_6 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 6 & 3 & 0 &1  & \frac{1}{3} &L_3 \\ 
 & z & 0 & -5 & 10 & -7 & 3 & 0 & 0 &  & L_4
\end{matrix}$

$|-7|> |-5|$ so $P_3$ gets in the basis and $P_6$ gets out of the basis.

Then we get the following tableau:

$\begin{matrix}
B & c_B & b & P_1 & P_2 & P_3 & P_4 & P_5 & P_5 & \theta & \\ 
P_1 & -5 & \frac{2}{3} & 1 & 1 & 0 & -\frac{3}{2} & 0 & -\frac{7}{6} &  &L_1'=L_1-7L_3' \\ 
P_5 & 0 & \frac{7}{3} & 0 & 1 & 0 & -\frac{3}{2} & 1 & -\frac{17}{6} &  & L_2'=L_2-17L_3'\\ 
P_3 & -7 & \frac{1}{3} & 0 & 0 & 1 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 &\frac{1}{6}  & &L_3'=\frac{L_3}{6} \\ 
 & z & \frac{7}{3} & -5 & 10 & 0 & \frac{13}{2} & 0 & \frac76 &  & L_4'=L_4+7L_3'
\end{matrix}$

Have I maybe done something wrong? Because from the last tableau we get that $P_1$ gets out of the basis and $P_1$ gets in the basis...

**EDIT**: We could introduce the artificial variables as follows:

$$- \max (-5x_1+10x_2-7x_3+3x_4) \\ x_1+x_2+7x_3+2x_4+x_5=3 \\ -2x_1-x_2+3x_3+3x_4+x_6=2 \\ 2x_1+2x_2+8x_3+x_4+x_7=4 \\ x_i \geq 0, i=1,2, \dots, 7$$

At the first phase, we solve the linear programming problem $\min (x_5+x_6+x_7)$ under the new restrictions and at the second phase the initial problem, for which we will have found from the first phase a basic feasible solution.

The problem of the first phase can be written as follows:

$$ -\max (-x_5-x_6-x_7) \\ x_1+x_2+7x_3+2x_4+x_5=3 \\ -2x_1-x_2+3x_3+3x_4+x_6=2 \\ 2x_1+2x_2+8x_3+x_4+x_7=4 \\ x_i \geq 0, i=1,2, \dots, 7$$

Then I thought the simplex tableau would be the following:

$\begin{matrix}
B & c_B & b & P_1 & P_2 & P_3 & P_4 & P_5 & P_6 & P_7 & \theta & \\ 
P_5 & -1 & 3 & 1 & 1 & 7 & 2 & 1 & 0 & 0 &  & L_1\\ 
P_6 & -1 & 2 & -2 & -1 & 3 & 3 & 0 & 1 & 0 &  & L_2\\ 
P_7 & -1 & 4 & 2 & 2 & 8 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 &  & L_3\\ 
 & z & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 &  & L_4
\end{matrix}$

But I found that it is this one:

[image]

How do we find the $z_k-c_k$- values?

**EDIT 2**: I get the following tableaus:

$\begin{matrix}
B & c_B & b & P_1 & P_2 & P_3 & P_4 & P_5 & P_6 & P_7 & \theta & \\ 
P_1 & -1 & 3 & 1& 1&7  & 2 & 1 & 0 & 0 & \frac{3}{7} & L_1 \\ 
P_5 & -1 & 2 & -2 & -1 & 3 & 3 & 0& 1 & 0 &\frac{2}{3} &L_2\\ 
P_6 & -1 & 4 & 2 & 2 & 8 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 &\frac12 &L_3\\ 
 & z & -9& -1 & -2 & -18 & -6& 0& 0 & 0 & &
\end{matrix}$

$$$$

$
\begin{matrix}
B & c_B & b & P_1 & P_2 & P_3 & P_4 & P_5 & P_6 & P_7 & \theta & \\ 
P_3 & 0 & \frac{3}{7} & \frac{1}{7}& \frac{1}{7}&1  & \frac{2}{7}& \frac{1}{7} & 0 & 0 & \frac{3}{2} & L_1'=\frac{L_1}{7} \\ 
P_6 & -1 & \frac{11}{7} & \frac{-17}{7} & -\frac{10}{7} & 0 & \frac{15}{7} & -\frac{3}{7}& 1 & 0 &\frac{11}{15} &L_2'=L_2-3L_1'\\ 
P_7 & -1 & \frac{4}{7} & \frac{6}{7} & \frac{6}{7} & 0 & -\frac{9}{7} & -\frac{8}{7} & 0 & 1 &- &L_3'=L_3-8L_1'\\ 
 & z & \frac{-9}{7}& \frac{11}{7} & \frac{4}{7} & 0 & \frac{-6}{7}& \frac{18}{17}& 0 & 0 & & L_4'=L_4+18 L_1'
\end{matrix}$

$
\begin{matrix}
B & c_B & b & P_1 & P_2 & P_3 & P_4 & P_5 & P_6 & P_7 & \theta & \\ 
P_3 & 0 & \frac{23}{105} & \frac{7}{15}& \frac{1}{3}&1  & 0& \frac{1}{5} & -\frac{2}{15} & 0 &  & L_1''=L_1'-\frac{2}{7}L_2'' \\ 
P_4 & 0 & \frac{11}{15} & \frac{-17}{15} & -\frac{2}{3} & 0 & 1 & -\frac{1}{5}& \frac{7}{15} & 0 & &L_2''=\frac{7}{15} L_2'\\ 
P_7 & -1 & \frac{17}{5} &  -\frac{123}{35} & 0 & 0 & 0 & -\frac{7}{15} & \frac{9}{15} & 1 & &L_3''=L_3'+\frac{9}{7}L_2''\\ 
 & z & \frac{3}{5}& \frac{3}{5} & 0 & 0 & 0& \frac{12}{5}& \frac{6}{15} & 0 & & L_4''=L_4'+\frac{6}{7} L_2''
\end{matrix}$

$$$$

But according to my textbook it should be as follows:

[image]

Have I done something wrong at the calculations?

Comment: I think you can simplify matter by eliminating $y_1$ and $y_2$ first.  (i.e. re-write the objective function in terms of $y_3$ and $y_4$).  Then the optimal solution can be found easily.

Comment: @GNUSupporter So is the new form in which I have written the linear programming problem right, we just have to change the objective function? If so, how can we write it in therms of $y_3$ and $y_4$ ?

Comment: Change $y_1+y_2+7y_3+2y_4=3$ to $y_1=3-(y_2+7y_3+2y_4)$, and substitute it to the objective function and the other constraints, and repeat this for $y_2$ and $y_3$, then only $y_4$ will be left.

Comment: @GNUSupporter A ok... You mean after having introduced the artificial variables? Or don't we have to introduce them?

Comment: I guess you don't have to do so.  Maybe I present you a quicker way to get the solution.  Btw, in response to your question, the first tableau is *not* yet a simplex tableau because you have not yet make $z_1 - c_1$ zero.  You need to replace $L_4$ by $5L_1 + L_4$ first.

Comment: If we write the matrix in its row echelon form, how can we find the new values of $z_k-c_k$ ? @GNUSupporter

Comment: @GNUSupporter I have written the objective function as $\frac{43}{2}y_4+\frac{133}{3}$. Why should I do so? In order to find the maximum value with an other method?

Comment: I'm sorry for wasting your effort.  I overlooked the constraint $y_i \ge 0$.  I saw it as $y_1$ free.

Comment: @GNUSupporter No problem... Do you have an idea how we can use the simplex method in this case? Do we have to introduce artificial variables or don't we have to?

Comment: Use the two-phase method.  I'm typing the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The original minimization problem

\begin{align}
  \min z = 5y_1-10y_2+7y_3-3y_4 & \\
  y_1+y_2+7y_3+2y_4 &= 3 \\
  y_2+17y_3+7y_4    &= 8 \\
  6y_3+3y_4         &= 2 \\
  y_i &\geq 0, i \in \{ 1, \dots, 4 \}
\end{align}

We try to find a basic feasible solution to the original LPP by the two-phase method.  Add the artificial variables $y_5,y_6 \ge 0$ into the LPP.

\begin{align}
  \min z = y_5+y_6 & \\
  y_1+y_2+7y_3+2y_4  &= 3 \\
  y_2+17y_3+7y_4+y_5 &= 8 \\
  6y_3+3y_4+y_6      &= 2 \\
  y_i &\geq 0, i \in \{ 1, \dots, 6 \}
\end{align}

We write the objective function as $z-y_5-y_6=0$.  Since the coefficient of $z$ is always one, we omit it in the simplex tableaux to save ink.

\begin{equation*}
  \begin{array}{rrrrrrr|r}
        & y_1 & y_2 & y_3 & y_4 & y_5 & y_6 &   \\ \hline
    y_1 &   1 &   1 &   7 &   2 &   0 &   0 & 3 \\
    y_5 &   0 &   1 &  17 &   7 &   1 &   0 & 8 \\
    y_6 &   0 &   0 &   6 &   3 &   0 &   1 & 2 \\ \hline
      z &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &  -1 &  -1 & 0
  \end{array}
\end{equation*}

Make it a simplex tableau.

\begin{equation*}
  \begin{array}{rrrrrrr|r}
        & y_1 & y_2 & y_3 & y_4 & y_5 & y_6 &    \\ \hline
    y_1 &   1 &   1 &   7 &   2 &   0 &   0 &  3 \\
    y_5 &   0 &   1 &  17 &   7 &   1 &   0 &  8 \\
    y_6 &   0 &   0 &   6 &   3 &   0 &   1 &  2 \\ \hline
      z &   0 &   1 &  23 &  10 &   0 &   0 & 10
  \end{array}
\end{equation*}

Since it's minimization, we choose $y_j$ with the biggest $z_j - c_j$ as the entering variable.

\begin{equation*}
  \begin{array}{rrrrrrr|rr}
        & y_1 & y_2 & y_3 & y_4 & y_5 & y_6 &    &       \theta \\ \hline
    y_1 &   1 &   1 &   7 &   2 &   0 &   0 &  3 &  \frac{3}{7} \\
    y_5 &   0 &   1 &  17 &   7 &   1 &   0 &  8 & \frac{8}{17} \\
    y_6 &   0 &   0 & 6^* &   3 &   0 &   1 &  2 &  \frac{1}{3} \\ \hline
      z &   0 &   1 &  23 &  10 &   0 &   0 & 10 &
  \end{array}
\tag{*} \label{min}
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
  \begin{array}{rrrrrrr|rr}
        & y_1 & y_2 & y_3 &          y_4 & y_5 &           y_6 &             &       \theta \\ \hline
    y_1 &   1 & 1^* &   0 & -\frac{3}{2} &   0 &  -\frac{7}{6} & \frac{2}{3} &  \frac{2}{3} \\
    y_5 &   0 &   1 &   0 & -\frac{3}{2} &   1 & -\frac{17}{6} & \frac{7}{3} &  \frac{7}{3} \\
    y_3 &   0 &   0 &   1 &  \frac{1}{2} &   0 &   \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{3} &              \\ \hline
      z &   0 &   1 &   0 & -\frac{3}{2} &   0 & -\frac{23}{6} & \frac{7}{3} &
  \end{array}
\end{equation*}

Choose $y_2$ as the entering variable, $y_1$ as the leaving variable.

\begin{equation*}
  \begin{array}{rrrrrrr|r}
        & y_1 & y_2 & y_3 &          y_4 & y_5 &          y_6 &             \\ \hline
    y_2 &   1 &   1 &   0 & -\frac{3}{2} &   0 & -\frac{7}{6} & \frac{2}{3} \\
    y_5 &  -1 &   0 &   0 &            0 &   1 & -\frac{5}{3} & \frac{5}{3} \\
    y_3 &   0 &   0 &   1 &  \frac{1}{2} &   0 &  \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{3} \\ \hline
      z &  -1 &   0 &   0 &            0 &   0 & -\frac{8}{3} & \frac{5}{3}
  \end{array}
\end{equation*}

Since we still have the artificial variable $y_5$ in the basis in the optimal tableau, we conclude that this problem is not feasible.

I tried phase one in GNU Octave.  You may run the following code [online](http://octave-online.net).

```
A=[1 1 7 2 0 0; 0 1 17 7 1 0; 0 0 6 3 0 1];
b = [3 8 2]'; c=[0 0 0 0 1 1]';
[x_min z_min] = glpk(c,A,b,zeros(6,1),[],"SSS","CCCCCC")
```

Results

```
x_min =

   0.00000
   1.66667
   0.00000
   0.66667
   1.66667
   0.00000

z_min =  1.6667
```

I also tried directly solving the original LPP, and the program returned `NA`.

```
A = [1 1 7 2; -2 -1 3 3; 2 2 8 1]; b = [3 2 4]'; c = [5 -10 7 -3]';
[x_min,z_min] = glpk(c,A,b,zeros(4,1),[],"SSS","CCCC")
```

Result

```
glp_simplex: unable to recover undefined or non-optimal solution
x_min =

    NA
    NA
    NA
    NA

z_min = NA
```

---

To get $z_j - c_j$, you may simply calculate $c_B^T B^{-1} a_j$.  For the derivation, you may see [my answer for another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1595184/290189) about the regeneration of optimal simplex tableau from the optimal BFS.  **To actually calculate this number, compute $c_B^T y_j$, where $y_j$ is the column for $P_j$ in the current simplex tableau**.  For example, in the given tableau, $c_B = (-1,-1,-1)^T$.

\begin{align}
z_1 - c_1 &= (-1,-1,-1)(1,-2,2)^T = -1 \\
z_2 - c_2 &= (-1,-1,-1)(1,-1,2)^T = -2 \\
z_3 - c_3 &= (-1,-1,-1)(7,3,8)^T = -18 \text{, etc}
\end{align}

We want the artificial variables $x_5,x_6,x_7 = 0$, so we $\min x_5 + x_6 + x_7$, **which is equivalent to $\mathbf{\max -x_5 - x_6 - x_7}$ (what you see in your book)**.  That's why you see $-9$ in the $z$-row, $b$-column in the given simplex tableau.

Question: In simplex tableau $\eqref{min}$, the entering variable has $z_j - c_j > 0$.  This seems contradictory to what you've learnt.
Answer: See [my answer another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1594962/290189) for detailed explanation.

- **In a maximisation problem, the entering variable has $z_j - c_j \le 0$.**
- In a minimisation problem, the entering variable has $z_j - c_j \ge 0$.

\begin{array}{r|r|r|rrrrrrr|r|l}
  &     &      &      0 &    0 &     0 &      0 &   -1 &    -1 &  -1 &        &                                     \\        \hline
B & c_B &    b &    P_1 &  P_2 &   P_3 &    P_4 &  P_5 &   P_6 & P_7 & \theta &                                     \\ \hline \hline
  P_5 &  -1 &    3 &      1 &    1 &     7 &      2 &    1 &     0 &   0 &        &                                 L_1 \\
  P_6 &  -1 &    2 &     -2 &   -1 &     3 &      3 &    0 &     1 &   0 &        &                                 L_2 \\
  P_7 &  -1 &    4 &      2 &    2 &     8 &      1 &    0 &     0 &   1 &        &                                 L_3 \\        \hline
  &   z &    0 &      0 &    0 &     0 &      0 &    1 &     1 &   1 &        &                                 L_4 \\ \hline \hline
  P_5 &  -1 &    3 &      1 &    1 &   7^* &      2 &    1 &     0 &   0 &  3/7^* &                          L_1' = L_1 \\
  P_6 &  -1 &    2 &     -2 &   -1 &     3 &      3 &    0 &     1 &   0 &    2/3 &                          L_2' = L_2 \\
  P_7 &  -1 &    4 &      2 &    2 &     8 &      1 &    0 &     0 &   1 &    4/8 &                          L_3' = L_3 \\        \hline
  &   z &   -9 &     -1 &   -2 & -18^* &     -6 &    0 &     0 &   0 &        &       L_4' = -L_1 - L_2 - L_3 + L_4 \\ \hline \hline
  P_3 &   0 &  3/7 &    1/7 &  1/7 &     1 &    2/7 &  1/7 &     0 &   0 &    3/2 &                L_1'' = \frac17 L_1' \\
  P_6 &  -1 &  5/7 &    -17/7 &  -10/7 &     0 & 15/7^* & -3/7 &     1 &   0 & 5/15^* &         L_2'' = L_2' - \frac37 L_1' \\
  P_7 &  -1 &  4/7 &    6/7 &  6/7 &     0 &   -9/7 & -8/7 &     0 &   1 &      - &         L_3'' = L_3' - \frac87 L_1' \\        \hline
  &   z & -9/7 &   11/7 &  4/7 &     0 & -6/7^* & 18/7 &     0 &   0 &        &    L_4'' = L_4' + \frac{18}{7} L_1' \\ \hline \hline
  P_3 &   0 &  1/3 &   7/15 &  1/3 &     1 &      0 &  1/5 & -2/15 &   0 &        & L_1''' = L_1'' - \frac{2}{15} L_2'' \\
  P_4 &   0 &  1/3 & -17/15 & -2/3 &     0 &      1 & -1/5 &  7/15 &   0 &        &         L_2''' = \frac{7}{15} L_2'' \\
  P_7 &  -1 &    1 &   -3/5 &    0 &     0 &      0 & -7/5 &   3/5 &   1 &        &  L_3''' = L_3'' + \frac{3}{5} L_2'' \\        \hline
  &   z &   -1 &    3/5 &    0 &     0 &      0 & 12/5 &   2/5 &   0 &        &  L_4''' = L_4'' + \frac{2}{5} L_2''
\end{array}

Since artificial variable $P_7$ is still in the basis, this LPP has no feasible solution.

Comment: To use the simplex method we firstly write the linear programming problem in its canonical form , so $\min z=y_5+y_6$ becommes $- \max (-z=-y_5-y_6)$. $$$$
$-1$ is the smallest value at the last row, so do deduce that $P_5$ gets in the basis and $P_6$ gets out of the basis. This can't be true. $$$$
Or am I wrong?

Comment: @Evinda You may see the following table [my answer for another question][1] for a detailed description.

  \begin{array}{rr|l}
    & \text{a non-basic variable} & \text{RHS} \\ \hline
    \text{a basic variable} & \heartsuit > 0 & \spadesuit \ge 0 \\ \hline
    z & \clubsuit & \text{obj. fct. val.}
  \end{array}

After each pivot operation, you have

\begin{equation*}
  \text{new obj. fct. val.} = \text{obj. fct. val.} - \frac{\spadesuit\clubsuit}{\heartsuit}
\end{equation*}

[1]: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1594962/290189

Comment: @Evinda "$-1$ is smallest, so $P_5$ gets out of the basis" is true when (1) we are doing a **max**-type LPP, and (2) **it is a simplex tableau**

The problem is, in the first tableau of my answer, **it is not a simplex tableau**.  The two $-1$ in the last row is in the column $P_5$ and $P_6$, which is in the basis.  Therefore, to *make it a simplex tableau*, we do some row operations.

Comment: Directly using $\min z = y_5+y_6$ and remembering to choose the largest $z_j - c_j$ instead of converting it to a max-type and choosing the smallest $z_j - c_j$ LPP saves you one step.

Comment: I edited my post. Could you take a look at it?

Comment: @Evinda I've edited my answer in response to your edit.

Comment: I think that $L_4'=L_1+L_2+L_3+L_4$ isn't true, otherwise it should hold that $z_5'-c_5=2$. Or am I wrong? $$$$
Also could you explain me further how we get -9? Do we find the sum of the elements of the b-row and then take the minus of that? If so why do we do it like that?

Comment: Also I added my post since I do not get the same tableaus and thus the same solution as in my textbook. Have I done something wrong at the calculations?

Comment: @Evinda Sorry.  I've made 3 mistakes: (1) $L_4'=-L_1-L_2-L_3+L_4$ to ensure that if $P_j$ is a basic variable, $z_j - c_j$ **must be zero**.  This step is *very important*. (2) In the 3rd and 4th (i.e. last) objective function values $z$, I made a mistake.  I've corrected them.  Your book is correct.  However, I don't think that these mistakes will affect the conclusion that the LPP is infeasible because (1) **the rightmost column $L_1 = \dots$ is *unnecessary***, especially in test/exams.  Without that column, everyone still knows what you're doing. (pivot operation)

Comment: @Evinda (2) The optimality only depends on the $z_j - c_j$ of decision variables $P_j$, while the feasibility only depends on whether the entries in the $b$ column in the constraints row is non-negative. (i.e. whether $B^{-1} b \ge 0$)  **Neither the optimality nor the feasibility** has anything to do with the value of $z$.  We deduce that the LPP is infeasible from the entries in the $z$ row and in the $b$ column but excluding the objective function value, so that doesn't hurt.

Comment: @Evinda Btw, your book's tableau format is very clumsy.  You may use a better format with fewer to save time in tests/exams.
\begin{array}{crrrrrrr|l}
   & x_1 & x_2 & x_3 & x_4 & x_5 & x_6 &  x_7 & \\ \hline
   x_4 &   0 &  -3 &   7 &   1 &   0 &   0 &    2 & 2M  -4 \\
  x_5 &   0 &  -9 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   -1 & -M  -3 \\
  x_6 &   0 &   6 &  -1 &   0 &   0 &   1 & -4^* & -4M +8 \\
  x_1 &   1 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &    1 &      M \\ \hline
 &   0 &   1 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &    2 &     2M \\
\end{array}

Comment: @Evinda That is, you don't need to write the coefficients of $c_B$ in each step.  You can just do pivot operations normally to calculate the value of $z$.  Therefore, I get $-9$ in the second step (out of four steps) by $0 - 3 - 2 - 4$.

The above tableau is for the dual simplex algorithm, but I hope you know what I mean.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $L_2''=L_2'-3L_1''$ ?

Comment: Since $L_1'' = \frac17 L_1'$, $L_2'' = L_2' - \frac37 L_1' = L_2' - 3L_1''$.  Anyways, this can omitted.

Comment: We have the tableau: $\begin{matrix}
B & c_B & b & P_1 & P_2 &  P_3 & P_4 & P_5 & P_6 & P_7 & \theta &  \\ 
P_5 & -1 & 3 & 1 & 1 & 7 & 2 & 1 & 0 & 0 & \frac{3}{7}&C_1\\ 
P_6 &  -1 & 2 & -2 & -1 & 3 & 3 & 0 & 1 & 0 & \frac{2}{3}&C_2\\ 
P_7 & -1 & 4 & 2 & 2 & 8 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & \frac{1}{2}&C_3\\ 
 & z & -9 & -1 & -2 & -18 & -6 & 0 & 0 & 0 & &
\end{matrix}$


$$$$

We deduce that $P_3$ gets in the basis , $P_5$ gets out of the basis and the pivot is $7$. So $C_1'=\frac{C_1}{7}, C_2'=C_2-3C_1', C_3'=C_3-8C_1', C_4'=C_4+18C_1'$.$$$$ At which point am I wrong?

Comment: @Evinda It's OK!

Comment: At the first edit part, aren't tha values of $z_j-c_j$ wrong? Since we have $z_k-c_k=1, k=5,6,7$ and all these values should be equal to zero.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34091/discussion-between-gnu-supporter-and-evinda).

Comment: Could I also ask you something else about the simplex method?

Comment: @Evinda OK!  Please ask.

Comment: I have verified it... But thank you!!! Are you maybe also familiar with dynamic programming?

Comment: @Evinda I'm sorry that I don't know dynamic programming

Comment: A ok... no problem... with non-linear programming? I have also there a question.

Comment: @Evinda I confess that I only know linear programming.  As you can see on my user card (which pops up after you hover your mouse on my user icon), I spend a few time on math outside class.  You may start another post so that others can upvote it and give you reputation.

Comment: Ok... no problem... thanks :)