# Why do some implementations of the simplex method use an identity matrix while others don't?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, simplex-method

I am working on an implementation of the [simplex method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex_algorithm). Ferguson's notes$^\color{magenta}{\star}$ don't include the identity matrix in the simplex tableau. My algorithm$^\color{magenta}{\dagger}$ seems to work (it passes multiple unit tests that compare its output to SciPy's linear programing function). However, every other resource I consult includes an identity matrix (e.g., [Simplex method - identity matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1600800)). What's going on? Is it more efficient to implement things without the identity matrix?

Here's an image from the linked PDF that demonstrates what I'm taking about. I also included a worked out example from the PDF.

---

[image: screenshot]

---

[image: screenshot]

---

**References**

<sub>$\color{magenta}{\star}$ Thomas S. Ferguson, [Linear Programming — a concise introduction](http://web.tecnico.ulisboa.pt/mcasquilho/acad/or/ftp/FergusonUCLA_LP.pdf) [PDF]</sub>

<sub>$\color{magenta}{\dagger}$ SymPy, [Add linear programing function using simplex method](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/pull/25277) [GitHub pull request]</sub>

Comment: " *My algorithm seems to work* .  "  Show an example.

Comment: @callculus42 there are worked out problems on page 55 of the Ferguson's pdf

Comment: Is the identity matrix just there to keep track of what is going on during the process? See https://www3.nd.edu/~dgalvin1/30210/30210_F07/presentations/dual_opt.pdf